# Which is the best Ethereum solution for small day today transaction? Like a asset exchange for $1-2

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereum-classic

Building a portal where customer can rent out asset for the cost of $1-2.
Is there any platform with low transaction cost but still make all the entries in the ledger?

Comment: There's a state-channel approach called [Raiden](http://raiden.network/) that will allow very low-cost payment channels. It's not finished, but looks promising

Answer (score 1):

Typical Ethereum transactions invoking a low complexity smart contract function call cost a few cent. That is a few percent of your overall asset rental fee of $1-2 if I understand correctly. Depending on the business case and the margins that you are planning to make, it could thus work out to run it on the public Ethereum blockchain. Alternatively maybe you dont need a public chain, you could have a private Ethereum chain and get it basically for free (except for running the network yourself) or alternatively go for another blockchain solution such as eris:db (by Monax) which can run the same Solidity contracts as you would run on the Ethereum chain. Maybe you could for a private setting also consider Hyperledger fabric, they are supposedly reaching a release for production end of this month.

Comment: thanks for the response. We would like to minimize the infrastructure cost in-terms of network setup.Due to this we have not opted for Hyperledger and private Ethereum. Is there any other solution available?

Comment: The up-side of using the public Ethereum net is that you have >5k nodes running your network and you virtually dont have to bother about the acquaintance of this thing. That's what you pay for with the few cent tx cost that I mentioned.